# How can I exclude a row in a SQL select query that has a many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many

I have three tables, including a many to many join table.

Table 1: events

```
+-------------------------+
| EventID | eventName     |
+-------------------------+
| 1       | Backyard BBQ  |
| 2       | Night Out     |
| 3       | Birthday Party|
+-------------------------+
```

Table 2: event_type

```
+-----------------------+
| typeID | typeName     |
+-----------------------+
| 1       | BBQ         |
| 2       | Happy Hour  |
| 3       | House Party |
+-----------------------+
```

Table 3: event_type_join

```
+---------------------------+
| joinID | eventID | typeID |
+---------------------------+
| 1      | 1       | 1      |
| 2      | 1       | 3      |
| 2      | 2       | 2      |
| 3      | 3       | 3      |
+---------------------------+
```

How would I write a SQL select statement to get all events that don't have a typeID = 3 - "house party"?

NOTE: An event could be associated to multiple event types as EventID 1 is both a BBQ and a House Party.

The result I'm looking for would only have the "Night Out" event.

As I add more events and event types, I would want to be able to limit on multiple event types at a time.

I've been playing around with different select statements and can't figure out how to remove or exclude a row that has a relationship with one of the joins.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM event_type_join etj
    WHERE etj.typeID = 3 AND etj.eventID = e.eventID 
)
```

The `NOT EXISTS` condition ensures that no record exists in the junction table with `typeID = 3` for the current event.

Note: since you already know the `typeID` of the event types that you want to avoid, you don't need to involve table `event_type` in the query.

Comment: It works! That's awesome. It also looks like I don't need to use a GROUP BY. I've never seen the SELECT 1 before. Instead of group by, it just selects one result from the query? Thank you!

Comment: @Will: welcome! `SELECT 1` is just an expression that discards the results. Since all we want is to know if a record `EXISTS`, we don't need any column in the results of the subquery..